# UPnP, device announcement only

Tags: c++, upnp

I know that there are nice UPnP stacks like "Developer Tools for UPnP Technologies" (http://opentools.homeip.net/dev-tools-for-upnp). This would work but I do not need all this functionality.
All I need is that I can see my device (in e.g. the Windows Explorer - Network tree) with a property page which publishes the device IP.

[image]

Is there a library that only announces the device?

Answer (score 3):

[GSSDP](https://developer.gnome.org/gssdp/unstable/) (libgssdp in most linux distros) is a small, reliable and well tested library that handles the announcement and discovery part of UPnP: it's trivial to write a small program that advertizes the device uri with GSSDP (see [example](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gssdp/tree/examples/test-publish.c)).

However, nothing guarantees that your Windows Explorer shows all SSDP announced devices. Maybe you do know what it does but I thought I should mention it might show only devices that look like UPnP devices, or it might show only devices that look like UPnP AV devices, or might even only show devices that look like DLNA supporting UPnP AV devices...